# sql представление

Tags: sql, view

```
Create view ClassesView 
as 
select distinct a.Ид, a.Класс, 
       COUNT((select * from Ученики where Класс = a.Ид)), 
       (b.Фамилия+' '+b.Имя+' '+b.Отчество) as Учитель 
from Классы a, Учителя b 
where a.Преподаватель in (select b.Ид 
                          from Учителя
                         )
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: `where a.Преподаватель in (select b.Ид from Учителя)` видимо надо переписать как `where a.Преподаватель=b.Ид`. И учитесь задавать вопросы, вы не описываете что вы хотите получить в результате запроса, может то что вы написали так и планировалось ... но мы то об этом не знаем

Comment: @Mike, Сообщение 130, уровень 15, состояние 1, процедура ClassesView, строка 1
Невозможно выполнить агрегатную функцию для выражения, содержащего выражение или вложенный запрос.
дело в count

Comment: Вот и укажите это в тексте вопроса (ссылка править под вопросом). И еще обязательно укажите какая у вас СУБД, они очень сильно отличаются по тому, что можно делать в view

Comment: @Mike, разобрался)

Comment: Вы бы тот IN все таки переписали. А то зачем то еще раз читаете таблицу Учителей в подзапросе с IN и при этом из нее ничего не берете

Comment: Если ты используешь Агрегатную_функцию COUNT необходимо также GROUP BY <все поля кроме count>; Кроме этого нужен LEFT JOIN к таблице Учителя;  Select a.Класс, b.Учителя, Count() From a Left Join b On а.Учитель = b.Учитель Where a.Учитель = &Параметр1 Group by a.Класс, b.Учителя

Answer (score -2):

```
Create view ClassesView 
as 
select distinct a.Ид, a.Класс, 
       (select COUNT(*) from Ученики where Класс = a.Ид) as Количетсво, 
       (b.Фамилия+' '+b.Имя+' '+b.Отчество) as Учитель 
from Классы a, Учителя b 
where a.Преподаватель in (
                          select b.Ид 
                          from Учителя
                         )
```